# Basis of $M \otimes N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

If $B_M$ and $B_N$ are basis of $A$-modules $M$ and $N$, 
respectively, then $B = \{u \otimes v ; u \in B_M, v \in B_N\}$ is basis of $M \otimes N$.

Comments:

I did $B_M = \{u_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $B_N = \{u_j\}_{j \in J}$. First I showed that $B$ is a generator set:

$\displaystyle m \otimes n = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^m a_iu_i  \right) \otimes \left(\sum_{j = 1}^n b_jv_j \right) =  \sum_{i = 1}^m   \sum_{j = 1}^n a_ib_i(u_i \otimes v_j).$

I find it difficult to show that the set is linearly independent. I took a null linear combination

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^la_k(u_k \otimes v_k) = 0 $. I do not know how to show that $a_k=0$, for all $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** : take a bilinear function $\beta : M \times N \to A$ with value $\beta(u_k,v_l) = \delta_{kl}$ on the basis. By the universal property of the tensor product you get a unique linear function $b : M \otimes N \to A$ with $b(u_k \otimes v_l) = \delta_{kl}$.

Now, if $\sum a_{k,l} (u_k \otimes v_l) = 0$ applyling $b$ gives $a_{k,l} = 0$, and so indeed the vectors $u_k \otimes v_l$ are linearly independant.

Notice that you should not restrict to the sum $\sum_k a_k u_k \otimes v_k$ but really take a sum $\sum_{k,l} a_{k,l} u_k \otimes v_l$.